# Go - math.MaxInt64 and Type Inference Error

Tags: types, go, inference

I've been working on metaprogramming involving packages and I've been running into the error `constant 9223372036854775807 overflows int` whenever `math.MaxInt64` and `math.MaxUint64` show up.

I've isolated it into two cases:

Valid

```
var a int64 = math.MaxInt64
b := interface{}(int64(math.MaxInt64))
```

Not Valid

```
a := math.MaxInt64
b := interface{}(math.MaxInt64)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/U1QDmFbV29

It seems like that Go doesn't do correct type inference.

Is this a bug or expected behavior? And if expect, does anyone know why?

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that you are running Go in a 32 bit environment. On a 64 bit machine both expressions are fine.

Comment: That's not it. Both my OS and Go are 64 bit.

Comment: are you sure? what does `go env GOARCH` output?

Comment: @TristanRice @JimB at least the playground has 32 bit ints - `GOARCH` there prints `amd64p32` which AFAIK means that an integer is 32 bit wide.

Comment: Works on my machine as expected 'Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64'

Comment: My bad. MaxInt64 works just fine on my system, but MaxUint64 doesn't.

Comment: See also [The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`math.MaxInt64` is an [`Untyped Constant`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants). Numeric constants represent values of arbitrary precision and do not overflow. When you assign this to a variable it needs to be converted to a numeric type, and if none is specified, `int` is used by default.

Since the `int` type in Go represents the native size for your architecture, this will overflow on systems with 32 bit `int`s.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it.